# After capture image and submitting it showing unfortunately stopped and Large Sized images won't uploading into mysql database in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am facing issue, after capturing image and submitting app get crashed.

Also, selecting large images from gallery won't upload into mysqldb apart from that all things are working fine for me.

Here is my java code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_detailes);
        spinnerCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
        spinnerCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCity);
        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGender);
        btnShowLocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGetLoc);
        area=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.area);
        spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.clickpic);
        textViewGpsLat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLat);
        textViewGpsLng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewGpsLng);
        serialno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sn);
        wareno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wn);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(EnterDetailes.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                String latitud=String.valueOf(latitude);
                String longitud=String.valueOf(longitude);
                textViewGpsLat.setText(latitud);
                textViewGpsLng.setText(longitud);

                // \n is for new line
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}
private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(EnterDetailes.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                // Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                    bitmapOptions);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator
                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            bitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}


public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

public void submit(View v) {
    District = spinnerCountry.getSelectedItem().toString();
    City = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString();
    SerialNo = serialno.getText().toString();
    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    Gender= radioSexButton.getText().toString();
    WareNo = wareno.getText().toString();
    Area= area.getText().toString();
    Latitude = textViewGpsLat.getText().toString();
    Longitude = textViewGpsLng.getText().toString();
    if (SerialNo.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You did'nt entered SerialNo",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if(WareNo.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You did'nt entered WareNo",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else{
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute();

    }
}


class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(EnterDetailes.this, "",
            "Submitting. Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String imagename=getStringImage(bitmap);

        InputStream is=null;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName",imagename));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("district",District));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",Gender));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city",City));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serialno",SerialNo));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",Area));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wareno",WareNo));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",Latitude));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",Longitude));

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://www.lorryguru.com/domains/dogs/submitdog.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();
            return "success";
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            return "No Internet";
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            return "No Internet";
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        dialog.hide();

        if(s.equals("success"))
        {

            s="Uploaded Successfully.";
            serialno.setText("");
            wareno.setText("");
            textViewGpsLat.setText("");
            textViewGpsLng.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            s="Check Your Internet. Make sure you turn on the Internet or WIFI";
        }
        Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If app gets crashed you can check error in logcat, post it here and don't post entire class in question, show relevant code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    resize the bitmap like this :

      public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

            Bitmap resizedBitmap = null;
            try {
                int width = bm.getWidth();
                int height = bm.getHeight();
                float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
                // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                //  matrix.postRotate(45);
                // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
                resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
                bm.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
///
            }
            if (resizedBitmap != null)
                return resizedBitmap;
            else
                return bm;
        }
```

Comment: where and how to use this resized bitmap reference

Comment: after onActivityResult when you got the bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                    bitmapOptions);
use bitmap